# Pandas: create multiple aggregate columns and merge multiple data frames in an elegant way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am using the following code to create a few new aggregated columns based on the column `version`. Then merged the 4 new data frames.

```
new_df = df[['version','duration']].groupby('version').mean().rename(columns=lambda x: ('mean_' + x)).reset_index().fillna(0)

new_df1 = df[['version','duration']].groupby('version').std().rename(columns=lambda x: ('std_' + x)).reset_index().fillna(0)
new_df2 = df[['version','ts']].groupby('version').min().rename(columns=lambda x: ('min_' + x)).reset_index().fillna(0)
new_df3 = df[['version','ts']].groupby('version').max().rename(columns=lambda x: ('max_' + x)).reset_index().fillna(0)

new_df3

import pandas
df_a = pandas.merge(new_df,new_df1, on = 'version')
df_b = pandas.merge(df_a,new_df2, on = 'version')
df_c = pandas.merge(df_b,new_df3, on = 'version')
df_c
```

The output looks like below:

```
    version  mean_duration  std_duration    min_ts                max_ts
0   1400422  451                1               2018-02-28 09:42:15   2018-02-28 09:42:15
1   7626065  426                601             2018-01-25 11:01:58   2018-01-25 11:15:22
2   7689209  658                473             2018-01-30 11:09:31   2018-02-01 05:19:23
3   7702304  711                80              2018-01-30 17:49:18   2018-01-31 12:27:20
```

The code works fine, but I am wondering is there a more elegant/clean way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you possibly supply some sample input data so we can test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `functools` `reduce` modify your result (`merge`)

```
import functools
l=[new_df1,new_df3,new_df3]
functools.reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['version']), l)
```

Or let us using `agg` recreate what you need

```
s=df.groupby('version').agg({'duration':['mean','std'],'ts':['min','max']}).reset_index()

s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Comment: Thanks. But s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join) gives very ugly column names like: v_e_r_s_i_o_n__ , t_s___m_i_n, t_s___m_a_x, d_u_r_a_t_i_o_n___m_e_a_n, d_u_r_a_t_i_o_n___s_t_d . Can we remove the _  within a word (okay to keep the _ between words)